# Cannot find type 'GADRequestError' in scope

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to integrate AdMob into my app. I've imported GoogleMobileAds into my MainViewController, but Xcode is showing an error message.

**Error message** - Cannot find type 'GADRequestError' in scope[image]

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The SDK [reference](https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/mobile-ads-sdk/ios/api/reference/Protocols/GADBannerViewDelegate#-bannerview:didfailtoreceiveadwitherror:) declares the method as:

```swift
optional func bannerView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: Error)
```

Try using that instead.

Comment: It looks like `GADRequestError` has been removed in v8 as detailed in https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/migration?hl=en#class_renames.